# VAE, CNN or lstm autoencoders code samples needed for non sequential data augmentation python

Tags: python, keras, lstm, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

This post may sound very simple but I have done a little search on this and couldn't find anything useful in Stackoverflow for data augmentation.

If someone could post a sample code for variational autoencoder, CNN autoencoder or lstm based data augmentation technique for the tabular data, that would be appreciated; some explanation on which of these techniques are suitable for tabular data would be great too.

Data set that I have is neither time-series based nor an image or text; it is just simple rectangular data of shape 4000 * 14. Columns are 14. Is there